# Bookshelf/Passport: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, bookshelf.js

I am running into some errors in the console for a route. The express route is the following:

```
router.get('/getInfo/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  return passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}, function(err, account, info) {
   if (err) { return next(err);}
   if (!account) { 
    new Account({_id: req.params.id}).fetch({columns: ['first_name']}).then(function(acc){ 
        return res.status(200).send(acc.toJSON());
    }); 
   }
   if(account._id != req.params.id) { 
    new Account({_id: req.params.id}).fetch({columns: ['first_name']}).then(function(acc){ 
        return res.status(200).send(acc.toJSON());
    });
   }
   else { 
    new Account({_id: req.params.id}).fetch().then(function(acc){ 
        return res.status(200).send(acc.toJSON());
    });
   }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Error message only appears when I am not authenticated - it says

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
...
at null.<anonymous> (/-----/routes/users.js:61:27)
```

Line 61 is the res.status(200).. in the block with (account._id != req.params.id).

The idea behind the code was that if you request information about a user that's not you (verified by the jwt) you only get some information - right now only the 'first_name'. If you request information about yourself, you see all information.

The thing that bugs me the most is that I still get a valid response every time I call the route. The server doesn't crash/refuses to load/.. - I get exactly what I expect.

Comment: you might want to do `return new Account(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it comes from an improper use of promises

The thing is that when you write this

```
if (!account) { 
    new Account({_id: req.params.id}).fetch({columns: ['first_name']}).then(function(acc){ 
        return res.status(200).send(acc.toJSON());
    }); 
   }
```

You are actually NOT returning from your function and instead create a new account and get a promised execution of `res.status(200)...` but you then continue to the next line `if ... else ...` where you are guaranteed also to get a promise of another `res.status(200)...`

So indeed you are trying to set headers twice  hence the error.

To solve this you have several solutions

(1) You add a ˋreturn` to all your lines in the ifs

```
router.get('/getInfo/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  return passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}, function(err, account, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err);}
    if (!account) { 
      return new Account({_id: req.params.id}).fetch({columns: ['first_name']}).then(function(acc){ 
        return res.status(200).send(acc.toJSON());
      }); 
    }
    if(account._id != req.params.id) { 
      return new Account({_id: req.params.id}).fetch({columns: ['first_name']}).then(function(acc){ 
        return res.status(200).send(acc.toJSON());
      });
    }
    else { 
      return new Account({_id: req.params.id}).fetch().then(function(acc){ 
        return res.status(200).send(acc.toJSON());
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

(2) You chain the ifs so that you are sure you only execute only one per call

```
router.get('/getInfo/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  return passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}, function(err, account, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err);}
    if (!account) { 
      new Account({_id: req.params.id}).fetch({columns: ['first_name']}).then(function(acc){ 
        return res.status(200).send(acc.toJSON());
      }); 
    } else if(account._id != req.params.id) { 
      new Account({_id: req.params.id}).fetch({columns: ['first_name']}).then(function(acc){ 
        return res.status(200).send(acc.toJSON());
      });
    } else { 
      new Account({_id: req.params.id}).fetch().then(function(acc){ 
        return res.status(200).send(acc.toJSON());
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

(3) Or you restructure your code a bit to be a bit more in line with the intent of promises. Actually you have 3 different ways to create an account but only one way to end the call. I would make that more explicit. That would give something like

```
router.get('/getInfo/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  return passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}, function(err, account, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err);}
    let createAccountPromise;
    if (!account) { 
      createAccountPromise = new Account({_id: req.params.id}).fetch({columns: ['first_name']});
    } else if(account._id != req.params.id) { 
      createAccountPromise = new Account({_id: req.params.id}).fetch({columns: ['first_name']});
    } else { 
      createAccountPromise = new Account({_id: req.params.id}).fetch();
    }

    return createAccountPromise
      .then(function(acc){ 
        return res.status(200).send(acc.toJSON());
      }); 
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! I decided to use (3) and look into promises.